# Resolving a Slack user ID without mentioning the user

Tags: slack

According to the [Slack docs](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames), I should use `<@W123>` syntax.  However, this turns into `@joe`, which alerts joe that someone messaged them. Is there any syntax like `<W123>` that resolves to just the user's display name?

(I am aware that I could use [user.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info), but so far I've avoided making any API calls and I was hoping I could keep that going.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got [a response](https://twitter.com/SlackAPI/status/938156711361372161) from @SlackAPI on Twitter.  Unfortunately, there is no markdown-y way to do this.  On the plus side, they have a good sense of humor.

Comment: Is this answer still true? More than 5 years have passed and I wonder